# Java most efficient way to assign data values to multiple key dependencies

Tags: java, key-value-store, coding-efficiency

*What I'm trying to do*: I have a set of golf club objects(~60 clubs). Depending on the club name and club level(1-10 levels), each one will have a different maxmultiplier and minmultiplier value associated with it that I will need to perform calculations.

*What I've thought about*:
Using switch statement for the club levels and a hashmap to pair the club name with an array of the multipliers in order to retrieve the correct values. Issue I have with this would be that I would have to create ~60 separate 2item arrays for the multipliers. Thought about 2d arrays and so forth but I'm at the point where it feels like I'm going in circles. I know I CAN get it to work through brute force but I'm trying to work on efficiency. Is there a way to set this up in a localized way(table-like structure) that would make it easy to retrieve?

*Things to Note*: Java is my first language,I'm trying to learn, I'm at the skill level where I can MAKE things work but am transitioning into learning best practices. So for answers If we could stick with basic/intermediate java ideas that would be appreciated. But after I get it working next step will be implementing serializable to store data outside the program and learning that, followed by storing information in a SQL database which ultimately seems the easiest in my mind using a table.
Here is some of my code:

```
    /*
    * Creates all the clubs to be used in the app
    */
    public ClubSet() {

    clubMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>(100, (float) 0.8);
    clubMap.put("DRIVER", driverArray);//all the club names of driver type
    clubMap.put("WOOD", woodArray);
    clubMap.put("LONG", longArray);
    clubMap.put("SHORT", shortArray);
    clubMap.put("WEDGE", wedgeArray);
    clubMap.put("ROUGH", roughArray);
    clubMap.put("SAND", sandArray);

    for (HashMap.Entry<String, String[]> entry : clubMap.entrySet()) {
      for (String clubName : entry.getValue()) {
        Club club = new Club(entry.getKey(), clubName);
        this.put(club, club.getClubType());
        }
      }
    }

    /*
    * Returns a set of all clubs according to clubtypre(e.g. Driver,Wood,Long
    * Iron,etc)
    */
    public HashSet<Club> getClubSet(String clubType) {
    HashSet<Club> clubSet = new HashSet<Club>();
     if (this.containsValue(clubType)) {
      for (HashMap.Entry<Club, String> entry : this.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(clubType)) {
           clubSet.add(entry.getKey());
           }
        }
      }
    return clubSet;
     }
   }





public class Club {

private String clubType;
private String clubName;
private int level;
private ImageIcon imageIcon;
private String rarity;
private double maxMultiplier;
private double minMultiplier;
private HashMap<String, String[]> rarityMap;

private final String[] starterArray = new String[] { "BEGINNER DRIVER", "BEGINNER WOOD", "BEGINNER LONG",
        "BEGINNER SHORT", "BEGINNER WEDGE", "BEGINNER ROUGH", "BEGINNER SAND" };

private final String[] commonArray = new String[] { "ROCKET", "QUARTERBACK", "VIPER", "SNIPER", "BACKBONE",
        "SATURN", "RUNNER", "CLAW", "DART", "SKEWER", "MACHETE", "DESERT STORM", "SAND LIZARD" };

private final String[] rareArray = new String[] { "EXTRA MILE", "ROCK", "BIG DAWG", "GUARDIAN", "GOLIATH",
        "GRIZZLY", "APACHE", "THORN", "HORNET", "DOWN-IN-ONE", "RAPIER", "ROUGHCUTTER", "RAZOR", "NIRVANA",
        "MALIBU", "HOUDINI" };

private final String[] epicArray = new String[] { "APOCALYPSE", "BIG TOPPER", "THOR'S HAMMER", "HORIZON",
        "CATACLYSM", "HAMMERHEAD", "GRIM REAPER", "B52", "TSUNAMI", "KINGFISHER", "FALCON", "FIREFLY", "BOOMERANG",
        "ENDBRINGER", "JUNGLIST", "OFF ROADER", "AMAZON", "CASTAWAY", "SAHARA", "SPITFIRE" };

public Club() {
    this.clubType = null;
    this.clubName = null;
    this.level = 1;
    rarity = null;
//    maxMultiplier = 0;
//    minMultiplier = 0;

}

public Club(String clubType, String clubName) {
    this.clubName = clubName;
    this.clubType = clubType;
    this.level = 1;

    if (Arrays.asList(starterArray).contains(clubName)) {
        this.rarity = "STARTER";
    } else if (Arrays.asList(commonArray).contains(clubName)) {
        this.rarity = "COMMON";
    } else if (Arrays.asList(rareArray).contains(clubName)) {
        this.rarity = "RARE";
    } else if (Arrays.asList(epicArray).contains(clubName)) {
        this.rarity = "EPIC";
    }
 //       setMultipliers(clubName);

 }
```

Comment: If you want to use `contains`, a `HashSet` will be way faster. I would just create two `HashMap`, one with the club name as key and club instance as value; and one with the level as key then a `HashSet` as values (since there are multiple clubs with the same levels).

Comment: Looks like you want those arrays in Club  to be static.

Comment: @swpalmer yes you're right. Don't want to create new arrays on every instance of club.Thanks.

Comment: @Guillaume Not quite sure how I would use your first hashmap but you did give me an idea. I'll try creating a Hashmap with club name as the key and the second hashmap as the value. From there I should be able to get the min/max values by level. Thanks